# What do they mean by scope of the program in c language?

Tags: c, volatile

While declaring the volatile keyword, the value of variable make change any moment from outside the scope of the program. What does that meant? Whether it will change outside the scope of main function or outside the scope of globally declared function? What is the perspective in terms of embedded system, if two or more events are performed simultaneously?

Comment: Try to rephrase the question, so it's easier to understand what you're asking?

Comment: This might help to see better what this keyword should do : [C-Volatile-Keyword](https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/C-Volatile-Keyword)

Comment: https://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4023801/Introduction-to-the-Volatile-Keyword

Comment: "_Outside the scope of the program_" is a somewhat inaccurate description.  You should include a citation of where you are reading that to provide context.  It would be more accurate to say "_outside the accessing thread context_".

Comment: Sounds good! When I was asking the question, I didn't have a clarity of thinking volatile keyword in perspective of thread context. Thus, the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`volatile` was originally intended for stuff like reading from a memory mapped hardware device; each time you read from something like a memory address mapped to a serial port it might have a new value, even if nothing in your program wrote to it. `volatile` makes it clear that the data there may change at any time, so it should be reread each time, rather than allowing the compiler to optimize it to a single read when it knows your program never changes it. Similar cases can occur even without hardware interference; asynchronous kernel callbacks may write back into user mode memory in a similar way, so reading the value afresh each time is sometimes necessary.

Comment: That was never the _only_ original use. C is not thread-aware so the "_scope of the program_" (as described in the question) is somewhat inaccurate description; it should be "_within the thread context_". - a thread in this sense includes _interrupt handlers_.  It was always thus, not added later.

Comment: So you meant instead of &quot;scope of program&quot;, it should be &quot;within the thread&quot; context. If C is not thread aware, then do u mean volatile qualifer is defined for  Embedded C

Answer (score 0):

Ab optimizing compiler assumes there is only the context of a single thread of execution. Another context means anything the compiler can't see happening at the same time. So this is hardware actions, interrupt handlers or other threads or processes. Where your code accesses a global (program or file level) variable the optimizer won't assume another context might change or read it unless you tell it by using the volatile qualifier.

Take the case of a hardware register that is memory mapped and you read in a while loop waiting for it to change. Without volatile the compiler only sees your while loop reading the register and if you allow the compiler to optimize the code it will optimize away the multiple reads and never see a change in the register. This is what we normally want the optimizing compiler to do with variables that don't change in a loop.

A similar thing happens to memory mapped hardware registers you write to. If your program never reads from them the compiler could optimize away the write.  Again this is what you want an optimizing compiler to do when you are not dealing with a memory location that is used by hardware or another context.

Interrupt handlers and forked threads are treated the same way as hardware. The optimizer doesn't assume they are running at the same time and skip optimizing away a load or store to a shared memory location unless you use volatile.